# Disable Confirmation Dialogs in Finder for iCloud Drive

Tags: macos, finder, icloud

Is it possible to disable the confirmation dialog when moving/removing/deleting a file from iCloud Drive? The constant barrage of dialogs is incredibly irritating - I understand that removing the file from iCloud Drive will result in the file being removed from all of my iCloud Devices.

There is no Finder preference that I could find, and a Google search has not yielded anything.

Comment: What's the larger context? what's causing you to delete things continually from the cloud folder? Perhaps we can script that for you or suggest an alternative...

Comment: I'm using it as a drop box for any files I'm actively working on so that they are available between my 2 Macs.  I don't use it for permanent storage; this is kept locally on one of the machines.  I appreciate the thought towards a programmatic solution, but in this case I'm doing most of the file management individually through the Finder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of macOS 10.12 Sierra, this is possible through Finder's preferences:

> Show warning before removing from iCloud Drive

[image: Finder Preverences]

Comment: This is now the correct answer. Also, glad to discover the folders on top preference finally!

Comment: You can also set this from command line. Helpful if you apply multiple settings at once from a script
`defaults write com.apple.finder FXEnableRemoveFromICloudDriveWarning -bool false`

Comment: still works on macOs BigSur 11.5 !

Answer (score 3):

It has not been implemented yet (as of version 10.11.2), so no. I submitted a feedback request, but the more people request it, the more likely it will be added in further versions of OS X. To request it, go to : http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: That's really too bad!  I have also submitted a feedback request; I can only hope that more people do the same.  Thanks for confirming that it's not currently possible.