# Disable confirmation before creating file beginning with a dot in Finder

Tags: finder, catalina, macos

When I attempt to create a file beginning with a dot in Finder, I get a confirmation prompt asking if I really want that. The text of the prompt reads:

> Are you sure you want to use a name that begins with a dot “.”? The system treats items with these names as invisible files.

Attached is a photo of the dialog. I'm hoping to find a `defaults write` or similar configuration option to allow me to disable this confirmation dialog.

macOS version is 10.15.2.

[image: Confirmation dialog asking if I would like to use a name that begins with a dot "."]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263357/313842 would the second item "changing an extension " apply here ?

Comment: @ankii unfortunately, that option does not prevent this popup