# Disable confirmation dialog when moving files in iCloud Drive in Windows 10

Tags: icloud, windows

My question is similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170277/disable-confirmation-dialogs-in-finder-for-icloud-drive) but when using iCloud Drive in Windows (more specifically Windows 10). How can I stop iCloud Drive asking me for confirmation when I move files in the Windows Explorer?

[image]

This is specially annoying because many of the operations are just a rename (Ok, a move operation, but within the same directory), or move within iCloud itself. Also, a lot of times the Windows Explorer remains on top and you don't see the message, getting stuck until you realize why the action is blocked.

Comment: I'm not aware of a solution to this, but would love to see one found if possible.

Answer (score 0):

in windows go to icloud Drive in file Explorer and open the ".Trash" Folder (you have to enable "show hidden files" in explorer) select all files in the folder (if there are no files create some text files inside your icloud drive and delete them after they got uploaded) right click on the selected files and click delete, now there should be a popup window where you can add a check mark. check it and click OK.
now if you delete files inside your icloud drive folder it shouldn't ask you for confirmation anymore.
Problem solved

if you move multiple folders/files out of icloud drive it will now ask you just once for confirmation instead of for every single file

took me a while until I figured that out, hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot verify it since I don't have any `.Trash` directory inside `iCloud Drive`.

Comment: @cbuchart It's a hidden folder, you have to turn on the "Show hidden files and folders" option in Windows Explorer

Comment: To the answerer: What you described "works", but it does not stop iCloud Drive from prompting when you edit a file from iCloud Drive and save it.  Clearly, iCloud is interpreting the deletion that occurs as part of the save as a true deletion.